# Is it safe to use XMLDecoder to read document files?

Tags: java, security, xml-serialization, javabeans, xml-deserialization

Serializing Java Beans to XML using [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [`XMLDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) seems like a pretty neat approach: many classes from many sources can be serialized reliably, just using their public interface. Using this aproach to serialization is even suggested in many places of the API reference. But the [XML syntax](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/persistence3-139471.html) used for this seems quite powerful. Are there any security mechanisms which will prevent attacks originating from malicious documents? Or should the use of `XMLDecoder` on untrusted documents be avoided for security reasons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The deserialization of XML-serialized beans can cause prety much any operation which the JVM can perform. To give you an ugly examle, consider the following document which will write a certain file without any questions being asked:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<java version="1.4.0" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
  <object class="java.io.PrintWriter">
    <string>/tmp/Hacked.txt</string>
    <void method="println">
      <string>You have been hacked!</string>
    </void>
    <void method="close"/>
  </object>
</java>
```

This is roughly  the same as a method

```java
PrintWriter deserialize() {
    PrintWriter obj = new PrintWriter("/tmp/Hacked.txt");
    obj.println("You have been hacked!");
    obj.close();
    return obj;
}
```

**For this reason, I *strongly* advise *against* simply reading data from untrusted sources using `XMLDecoder`.**

Either validate the document to a well-defined and harmless subset of the XML language, or use your own formats together with technologies such as [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb). Or perform the deserialization in a tightly controlled environment, with security managers which will disallow any unexpected operation.

Comment: Indeed. Guideline 3-8 of the current Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language "Long Term Persistence of JavaBeans Components supports execution of Java statements." http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#3-8

Comment: @MvG , is there way by which I can generate an xml dump from any random object from the example above ? I tried with  XMLEncoder / XStream but I could not get the exact sytax like you xml equivalent to the the deserialize() implementation.

Answer (score 4):

NO it absolutely is not safe to use.

The example MvG provide (in the accepted answer) doesn't paint the full picture.

Take a look at the examples I wrote on the [Using XMLDecoder to execute server-side Java Code on an Restlet application (i.e. Remote Command Execution)](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/08/using-xmldecoder-to-execute-server-side.html) blog post where I show how to:

- Start processes,
- upload class files,
- write to server-side HTML OutputStream,
- create XSS and
- trigger a remote shell

all from XML files/strings that are parsed by XMLDecoder (and in the example shown in the blog post, via the Restlet's REST API ObjectRepresentation class)

Comment: To me, my answer demonstrated arbitrary code execution, and all the other aspects you describe are just symptoms of this. But I guess not everyone might make that connection, to server processes in particular, so it is good to state this explicitly. And having found a vulnerable framework makes this a lot more tangible. Have you contacted Restlet devs about this?